# Boost Converter With Constant Current Source

Tags: current, power-electronics, current-source, current-limiting, constant-current

I want to design boost converter but not like general converter. This boost converter will be include constant current source feature.

I designed buck converter version before

**

I used LM2596 and LM358.

Input --> 12V - 45V

Output --> Adjustable constant current source

**

Now I want to design boost version.

I will use XL6019 boost converter ([XL6019 Datasheet][1])

And I want to design adjustable constant current source. I'm sharing a screenshot of a circuit I've tried before.
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

This circuit didn't work(I observed output at maximum voltage level -- 70V). I didn't understand why it's not working (this method worked for buck converter).

Do you have any advice for me?

This advice can be different from my method.

EDIT:

My load is a resistor. I want it to draw the same current even if the resistance value rises when it heats up.

For Example;

Res = 10 ohm --> output is ** 24V _ 2,4A **

After 10 minutes

Res= 11 ohm ---> output is ** 26,4V _ 2,4A **

Actually what i want to do is something like led driver. My load is Electromagnetic Brake. like a resistor-inductor
[1]: https://cdn.ozdisan.com/ETicaret_Dosya/518032_5155360.PDF
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iipNu.png

Comment: Welcome! Please elaborate on _"this circuit didn't work"_. What does happen? How does it behave? Please show oscillograms.

Comment: What is your load (full details please)? What constant current are you trying to feed into the load? Is the load ground referenced or can it be floating (as per an LED current source)? What limits is the current to be adjustable? What are your power source characteristics?

Comment: I have edited for your questions.

Comment: If your end goal is a resistor, there is no difference in supplying constant voltage or constant current. If your end goal is something different, for example a LED, constant current makes perfect sense. What voltage do you have on the FB pin with 70 V output?

Comment: I'm assuming that the load will be across LOAD_A and LOAD_B nodes. Since the XL6008 tries to keep the FB node voltage at 1.25V, what you can do is to tie the top end of the current sense resistor (R4) to FB node directly. In this way, the output current will be 1.25V/R4 so adjust R4 accordingly. The bad thing about this design is that the output goes to infinite (theoretically) when unloaded.

Comment: Rohat Kılıç i want to ask something.. Will the r4 resistor be between feedback and ground?

Comment: winny actually what i want to do is something like led driver. My load is Electromagnetic Brake. like a resistor-inductor

Comment: @İbrahimEthemDERE yes, place the sense resistor across FB and GND and remove the amplifier (LM358 and its external components). The IC will try to keep the voltage across it at 1.25V so it'll work as a constant current source. Don't run the regulator without a load. Get the basic idea working first.

Comment: @RohatKılıç Thanks for reply but How do I determine the output current? For example, when I want to set the output current as 1A, how do I do this? I want it to be adjustable current source

Comment: @İbrahimEthemDERE I already explained it in my previous comment.

Comment: @RohatKılıç I tried now... Vin=24V ... R4=1 ohm ... Load=30 ohm .. It didn't work for current source